# Is there a way to associate an ArrayList with another ArrayList with a one to many relationship?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

My question is that if I have two classes named **Person** and **Book** and  with an `ArrayList` in each class, the **Person** `List` having a list of people and the **Book** having a list of books. Is it possible to make it so that each **Person** can have a different list of **Books**?

Say that I have a **Person** Class as such:

```
List<Person> person = new ArrayList<>();

Person(int name, int lastName, int age){
   //initialize variables
}
```

And a **Book** Class as such:

```
List<Book> book = newArrayList<>();

Book(int id, int title, int authorLastName){
   //initialize variables
}
```

How would I be able to give each **Person** their own list of **Books** with the fields and methods set like the above code?

Comment: Why would the Person class hold a list of Person objects (and the same for the Book class)?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Person` class instead of `List<Book>` use `Map<Person,List<Book>>`, so that each person will have list of books. For that you need to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method in person class so that you can maintain unique `Person` objects as keys in `Map`

**Person**

```
public class Person   { 

    private String name; 
    private String lastName;
    private int age
    // getters, setters , no arg and all arg constructor   

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    { 
        if(this == obj) 
            return true; 


        if(obj == null || obj.getClass()!= this.getClass()) 
            return false; 

        // type casting of the argument.  
        Person per = (Person) obj; 
          // check conditions based on requirement 
        return (per.name.equals(this.name)  && per.age == this.age); 
    } 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() 
    { 
         // generate hashcode based on properties so that same person will have same hashcode
         return this.age; 
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Person class take `List<Book>` that way each person can have their own list of books.

```
Person(int name, int lastName, int age, List<Book> books){
   //initialize variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Map` object instead of 2 ArrayLists. For example, you could have a `Map` object that associates Strings with integers, which would be initialized as follows: 
`new Map<Integer, String>()`
Note that the first data type is the key and the second is the the type of the mapped values. You can find more information by consulting the Java API.